# Jekyll and SEO friendly pagination

Tags: seo, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-paginator

When I audit a website with free or paid tools such as Screaming Frog SEO Spider I get the following issues:

- **Pagination: Pagination URL Not in Anchor Tag**
- **Pagination: Sequence Error**

I am using Jekyll SEO tag (version release 2.8.0)

I did not find any fix on the developer's page (https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag) and the available documentation does not cover the matter. How can I resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

**DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM**

This problem occurs because with Jekyll SEO tag URLs contained in either, or both, the `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"` attributes of the page are not found as a hyperlink in an HTML anchor element on the page itself. Paginated pages should be linked to within regular links to allow users to click and navigate to the next page in the series. They also allow Google and other search engines to crawl from page to page, and PageRank/Page Authority to flow between pages in the series.

With **Jekyll SEO tag** paginated URLs are not linked to within `<a>` tags. According to SEO documentation, this does not facilitate them to be crawled and indexed, and pass PageRank/Page Authority onto any URLs they link to.

**RESOLUTION**

1. Open the Command Line Interface
2. Enter the following command: `gem info jekyll`

An output similar to the following result would be shown:

> ```
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> jekyll (4.x.x)
>     Authors: Tom Preston-Werner, Parker Moore, Matt Rogers
>     Homepage: https://jekyllrb.com
>     License: MIT
>     Installed at: <PATH>/ruby/3.2.0
> ```

**Prerequisites:** In the Jekyll folder `_includes` create the `file seo-paginator.html`

**Steps:**

From within the folder `3.2.0`

1. Open the `gems` folder
2. Open the `jekyll-seo-tag-2.8.0`
3. Open the folder `lib`
4. Make a backup of the `template.html` file
5. Open the `template.html` file
6. Cut the following strings:

> ```
> {% if paginator.previous_page %}
> <link rel="prev" href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | absolute_url }}">
> {% endif %}
> {% if paginator.next_page %}
> <link rel="next" href="{{ paginator.next_page_path | absolute_url }}">
> {% endif %}
> ```

And paste them in the `seo-paginator.html` file.

7. From within the `seo-paginator.html` file, replace the following strings:

> ```
> <link rel="prev" href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | absolute_url }}">
> <link rel="next" href="{{ paginator.next_page_path | absolute_url }}">
> ```

With the following strings:

> ```
> <a rel="prev" href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | absolute_url}}"></a>
> <a rel="next" href="{{ paginator.next_page_path | absolute_url}}"></a>
> ```

8. From within the Jekyll folder `_layouts` open the `default.html` file, and insert somewhere in the `body` element the following string:

> ```
> {% include paginator.html %}
> ```

9. Save the amended `template.html`, `seo-paginator.html`, and the `default.html` files.

Rebuild the website with Jekyll, and review the page source of the HTML page from the Web browser. Now you would notice that `<a>` tags are present.

###### I am not affiliated to any of the mentioned software or brands.